# Replace anchor text with the text of the clicked of the LI

Tags: jquery

I am looking to replace the anchor text of a.location-trigger with text of the selected locations.li

```
            <a class="location-trigger" href="#">US</a>
            <ul class="locations">
                <li>US</li>
                <li>CA</li>
                <li>FR</li>
                <li>DE</li>
                <li>HK</li>
                <li>JP</li>
                <li>UK</li>
            </ul>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should trigger `click()` event of `li`, `$(this)` represents the current `li` text and replaces it to the `<a></a>` text:

**Like this?**

```
$(".locations li").click(function(){
    $("a.location-trigger").text($(this).text());
});
```

[**Demo Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zd97e/1/)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$(".locations li").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().prev("a.location-trigger").text($(this).text());
});
```